# MS Ajax, Visual Studio, vsdoc MicrosoftAjax-vsdoc.js

Tags: ajax, vsdoc

Is there a vsdoc for ms ajax (MicrosoftAjax-vsdoc.js) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The debug version contains vsdoc decorators. `MicrosoftAjax.debug.js`

Comment: yep, well done.  At the top of my js file, I put 
/// <reference path="../MicrosoftAjax/20100604/MicrosoftAjax.debug.js" />
Sys.Net.WebServiceError( 
and then I got intellisense drop downs ...